# How do you set percentage in Google Visualization Chart API?

Tags: api, charts, google-visualization, number-formatting

How do you set the vertical axis to display percent such as 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
chart.draw(data, {vAxis: {format:'#%'} } );
```

To get comma for thousands, use `{format:'#,###%'}`.

See http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html

Answer (score 37):

```
var options = {
        title: 'Chart Title',
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 100,
            format: '#\'%\''
        } 
    };
```

Try escaping the % sign. I've used this to just append the % sign in the y axis.

Comment: It should be: vAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, format: '#\'%\'';}

Comment: you can also give it values as json objects with v and f parameters: {v: '45' f:'45%'} 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752199/can-i-customize-the-tooltip-text-in-a-google-geochart-chart

Comment: simply exchange double and single quotes like `format: "#.#'%'"` - this way Google does not recalculate (multiply with 100) your values

Comment: Thank you very much @sbrbot, your tip solved the problem here!

Answer (score 3):

Using bar charts, I found my results haphazard and I got to consistency by doing the following:
1. In your data column, set a value of 100, even if you add a dummy value of 100.
2. Select all the numeric cells in the column and format them using Format, Number, Normal
3. Now format them to % using Format, Number, Percent Rounded

Your graph should now show 100% on the vertical scale and if you have a dummy value for 100% you will want to hide it, so you can either format it by clicking on it in the graph and changing the color (but this doesn't seem to work every time) 
or go to 
Advanced Edit, 
Customize, 
Columns, 
select your column name (from the graphic legend) and set the bar color to None or whatever your background color is.

Good luck.