# How do I add a new line to the tooltip text in a Google Geochart chart?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm using Google's GeoChart API to generate a map of the US.  I want to highlight the states based on one value, but then display some extra information about each state in the tool tip that displays when you hover over a state.  I'd like the finished tool tip to look like this:

```
Nevada
Relevance: 4 ( the data driving the state highlight )
Data
More Data
```

The map works great, and I can add any text I want to the tooltip using the `PatternFormat()` function, but it strips or ignores all the new line options I've tried:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat('some data\nmore data');
formatter.format(data, [0], 1);
```

I've tried all of these new line options and none of them work:
`<br>`, `<br />`, `&#13;`, `&#10`, `&#x0A`, `&#x0D`, `\u000A`, `\u000D`, `\n`, `\r`, `\r\n`, `%0A`, `%0D`

Any suggestions on things to try or what actually works?  This seems possible in some of the other Google charts.

**The rendered HTML looks like this**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    google.load( 'visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['geochart'] } );
    google.setOnLoadCallback( drawRegionsMap );

    function drawRegionsMap()
    {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            [ 'State', 'Relevance' ],
            [ 'Arizona', 2 ],
            [ 'California', 4 ],
            [ 'Colorado', 1 ],
            [ 'Florida', 1 ],
            [ 'Georgia', 1 ],
            [ 'Idaho', 1 ],
            [ 'Illinois', 1 ],
            [ 'Indiana', 1 ],
            [ 'Iowa', 1 ],
            [ 'Kansas', 1 ],
            [ 'Kentucky', 1 ],
            [ 'Louisiana', 1 ],
            [ 'Maryland', 2 ],
            [ 'Montana', 1 ],
            [ 'Nevada', 2 ],
            [ 'New Mexico', 2 ],
            [ 'North Carolina', 1 ],
            [ 'North Dakota', 1 ],
            [ 'Oklahoma', 1 ],
            [ 'Oregon', 1 ],
            [ 'Pennsylvania', 1 ],
            [ 'South Carolina', 1 ],
            [ 'Tennessee', 1 ],
            [ 'Texas', 1 ],
            [ 'Utah', 2 ],
            [ 'Washington', 1 ],
            [ 'Wyoming', 1 ]
        ]);

        data.addRows([
            ['Has Distributor', 1],
            ['Sells Direct', 1]
        ]);

        var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat('data <br> <br /> &#13; &#10 &#x0A &#x0D \u000A \u000D \n \r \r\n %0A %0D more data');
        formatter.format(data, [0], 1);

        var options =
        {
            width:      286,
            region:     'US',
            resolution: 'provinces',
            colorAxis:  { colors: ['#abdfab', '#006600'] },
            legend:     'none'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart( document.getElementById( 'chart_div' ) );
        chart.draw( data, options );

    };

</script>

<div id="chart_div" style="width: 286px; height: 180px;"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what the rendered HTML looks like with any of these examples?

Comment: I added the rendered HTML to the question for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all my research and testing I am almost positive that **it is currently impossible to add a new line to the tooltip text inside a GeoChart**.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752199/can-i-customize-the-tooltip-text-in-a-google-geochart-chart) for the solution I eventually came up with.  This did not solve the new line problem, but reformatted the tooltip in a way that worked for my application and may help others.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming across this question you can set in the chart options `tooltip: {isHtml: true}` from [the docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#using-html-tooltips)

Answer (score 2):

Tested & working.  Save the data as a multi-line CSV.

To do this, format multi-lines to have quotes.

IMPORTANT - you have to use \r for the *real* end-of-line characters, not \r or \r\n like normal.

e.g.

```
123,456,"this\n\is\nfour\nlines",678\r
234,567,"another\nmulti",789\r
```

All google things that use this data from now-on understand how to show it with multi-lines properly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using [data table roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles).  In a nutshell, you add a new column with a role of `tooltip`, and then you can customize what appears however you'd like.

I've used this before successfully with line and column charts, but the [chart gallery](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) pages for line and column charts explicitly mention that they support roles, whereas the geo chart page does not.  That may not mean that they aren't supported; it may just not be a documented feature.